# Ionic 3 cordova-branch-sdk plugin not working (ios)

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

ionic 3 cordova branch sdk plugin not working in ios build its giving “branch.h file not found” error

System info:

> Ionic:
>
> Ionic CLI : 6.10.2 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli) Ionic
> Framework : ionic-angular 3.9.2 @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4
>
> Cordova:
>
> Cordova CLI : 8.1.1 (cordova-lib@8.1.0) Cordova Platforms : ios 4.5.5
> Cordova Plugins : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3,
> cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1, (and 15 other plugins)
>
> Utility:
>
> cordova-res (update available: 0.15.1) : 0.6.0 native-run (update
> available: 1.0.0) : 0.2.9
>
> System:
>
> ios-deploy : 1.9.4 NodeJS : v10.16.3 (/usr/local/bin/node) npm :
> 6.13.4 OS : macOS Catalina Xcode : Xcode 11.5 Build version 11E608c

Answer (score 0):

A .h file is a header file that belongs to the plugin's native code.
If that file is not found, its the plugin's code that is not properly available in the project. It either has been deleted after installation, or it was not included when the plugin was installed.

Check the plugin's code on Github to be sure which of these is the case. If the code being installed is missing the file, try installing a different branch of the plugin.